# Having a problem converting from MS to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am having a problem converting from ms to datetime. I get wrong datetime when printing.

I want to convert 1701092673 ms to datetime.

The result I am expecting is 2023-11-27 02:44:33

```
import datetime

ms = 1701092673
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print (dt)
```

python prints 1970-01-20 17:31:32
I also tried the code below:

```
import datetime

ms = 1701092673
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print (dt)
```

Python prints 2023-11-27 14:44:33

Comment: What's this got to do with SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

1701092673 is in seconds not in ms